# GMap Polyline position of center

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, polyline

When I create Gmap she needed to establish the center and zoom

> Once we've created a map via the GMap2
>   constructor, we need to initialize it.
>   This initialization is accomplished
>   with use of the map's setCenter ()
>   method. The setCenter () method
>   requires a GLatLng coordinate and a
>   zoom level and this method must be
>   sent before any other operations are
>   performed on the map, including
>   setting any other attributes of the
>   map itself.

Because of this route is not positioned at the center - this is an example http://grab.by/4OD6

I should on the basis of the coordinates to get the center?

And get a zoom which displays all objects map?

My code:

```
var TrainingGMap = Class.create (( 
  initialize: function (div_id, points, options) ( 
    this.options = Object.extend ((), options) 
    this.points = points; 
    this.map = new GMap2 (document.getElementById (div_id)); 
    this.map.setCenter (new GLatLng (this.points [0]. lan, this.points [0]. lon), 12); 
    this.map.setUIToDefault (); 
    this.set_route (); 
  ) 

  set_route: function () ( 
    var line = new Array (); 
    for (var i = 0; i <this.points.length; i + +) ( 
      line [i] = new GLatLng (this.points [i]. lat, this.points [i]. lon); 
    ) 
    var polyline = new GPolyline (line, "# aa0000", 5); 
    this.map.addOverlay (polyline); 
  ) 
));
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolve my problem

```
this.map.setCenter(polyline.getBounds().getCenter());
this.map.setZoom(this.map.getBoundsZoomLevel(polyline.getBounds()));
```

New code

```
var TrainingGMap = Class.create({
  initialize: function(div_id, points, options) {
    this.options = Object.extend({}, options)
    this.points  = points;
    this.map     = new GMap2(document.getElementById(div_id));
    this.map.setCenter(new GLatLng(this.points[0].lan, this.points[0].lon), 12);

    this.map.setUIToDefault();
    var line = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {  
      line[i] = new GLatLng(this.points[i].lan,this.points[i].lon);
    }
    var polyline = new GPolyline(line, "#aa0000", 5);

    this.map.setCenter(polyline.getBounds().getCenter());
    this.map.setZoom(this.map.getBoundsZoomLevel(polyline.getBounds()));
    this.map.addOverlay(polyline);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> var TrainingGMap = Class.create({
>     initialize: function(div_id, points, options) {
>       this.options = Object.extend({}, options)
>       this.points  = points;
>       this.map     = new GMap2(document.getElementById(div_id));
>       this.map.setCenter(new GLatLng(this.points[0].lan, this.points[0].lon), 12);

```
this.map.setUIToDefault();
var line = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {  
  line[i] = new GLatLng(this.points[i].lan,this.points[i].lon);
}
var polyline = new GPolyline(line, "#aa0000", 5);
var tengah=Math.round(polyline.getVertexCount()/2)-1;
this.map.setCenter(polyline.getVertex(tengah));
this.map.setZoom(this.map.getBoundsZoomLevel(polyline.getBounds()));
this.map.addOverlay(polyline);
```

}
});